# Retrieve module block from an hook function in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, configuration, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'm creating a block inside a module in drupal 8.2

```
/**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "news-slider",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("News slider"),
 * )
 */
class NewsSliderBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {

public function build() {
  $config = $this->getConfiguration();
  $param1 = $config['param1'];
}

public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);
  $config = $this->getConfiguration();
  ...
  return $form; 
}

public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $this->setConfigurationValue('param1', $form_state->getValue('param1'));
}
```

in my module file

```
function news_slider_page_attachments_alter(&$build) {
  $settings = \Drupal::config('news-slider');
  $param1= $settings->get('param1');
  $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['news_slider']['asset1']['param1'] = $param1;
}
```

in my module libraries yml

```
asset1:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/news_slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupalSettings
```

when in browser js console i try

```
drupalSettings.news_slider.asset1.param1
```

is every time null, i really do no understand where i'm wrong.

Possibly   $settings = \Drupal::config('news-slider'); in module hook?

asset1 is attached in template module file news-slider.html.twig

```
{{ attach_library('news_slider/asset1') }}
```